# Error: illegal start of expression

Tags: java

Начал учить java, попытался решить простую задачку, выходит ошибка из заголовка

```
     public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 5;
  int b = 3;
  int c = 4;
  isTriangle(a, b, c);
}

public class istriangle {
public static int isTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
  if(a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a){
    System.out.println("It is triangle");
  }
  System.out.println("This is not a triangle");
  return
}
```

Comment: во-первых метод `isTriangle()` ничего не возвращает, хотя ты обещал, что вернётся `int`, во-вторых забыл поставить после `return` точку с запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте попробуем по порядку:

`public class main` - названия классов пишутся с большой буквы

`public class istriangle` - вы создаете внутренний класс только ради того чтобы объявить в нем один статический метод, это делать в данном случае не нужно, метод может быть объявлен в самом классе `Main`

`public static int isTriangle` подразумевает что или после `return` должен оказаться тот самый `int`(вернуться целое число), или в сигнатуре метода лучше заменить `int` на `void`, указав тем самым что метод ничего не возвращает и `return` тут не требуется.

В конструкции `if (условие) {если да} else {если нет}` опреатор `else` куда то исчез. Синтаксис допускает запись одного оператора вслед за условным без фигурных скобок.
Посмотрим что получилось:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;
        int b = 3;
        int c = 4;
        isTriangle(a, b, c);
    }

    public static void isTriangle(int a, int b, int c) {
        if(a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a) System.out.println("It is triangle");
        else System.out.println("This is not a triangle");
    }
}
```